# No '...' candidates produce 'Range<String.Index>'

Tags: ios, string, swift3, range

While converting an old iOS app to Sift 3.0 I hit the following issue:
The code is:

```
cutRange = numberString.index(numberString.startIndex, offsetBy:2)...numberString.index(numberString.startIndex, offsetBy:5)
```

The error message I get is:

```
No '...' candidates produce the expected contextual result type 'Range<String.Index>' (aka 'Range<String.CharacterView.Index>')
```

I have seen a few post related to the subject, but was not very satisfied.

So what is the simplest way to solve this problem?

Comment: This seems to compile fine for me in a Swift 3 playground. I assume `numberString` is a `String`?

Comment: Yes numberString is a String.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Swift 3, two range operators generate different results:

- closed range operator `...` -> `ClosedRange` (by default)
- (half open) range operator `..<` -> `Range` (by default)

So, assuming your `cutRange` is declared as `Range<String.Index>`, you need to use half open range operator `..<`:

```
cutRange = numberString.index(numberString.startIndex, offsetBy:2)..<numberString.index(numberString.startIndex, offsetBy:6)
```

(Please do not miss the last offset is changed to `6`.)

Comment: OK. I will try. That means using "..." and using "..<" return different type of ranges?

Comment: @Michel, True. Swift 3 added some range types other than `Range` -- `ClosedRange`, `CountableRange` and `ClosedCountableRange`. And `...` cannot generate `Range` nor `CountableRange`.